# Share Hyper-V internal virtual switch

Tags: networking, windows-10, hyper-v

I have a desktop and a laptop, both running Windows 10 (anniversary update). The desktop is a Hyper-V server, hosting 3 VMs sharing an internal switch. In this way, applications running on the desktop can connect to the VMs using their static IP addresses.

I would like to somehow "share" the internal switch to the laptop, so that applications running on the laptop would be able to access the VMs using their static IPs. I don't want to allow to any other machine on the network to access these VMs.

How can I achieve this functionality?

Comment: @techraf: the internal switch allows connections from the host (the desktop). I'd like to share the connection to a different machine: the laptop.

Comment: That's non-trivial. There's no way to share an internal switch with a single physical machine other than the host. You could either connect your VMs to an external switch and configure firewall to allow the connections from the desktop and the laptop on each of them; or if the use case allows, you could use port forwarding on host and filter the connections on your desktop-host; or you could set up a VPN and connect the laptop via a tunnel.